# SpringBoot POSTGRESQL autoincrementa id de 2 en 2

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data, autoincremento

tengo un problema a la hora de guardar registros en mi `base de datos` `Postgres-SQL`. Cada vez que guardo un nuevo registro, no crea el siguiente `id`, si no el siguiente +1.

Por ejemplo, tengo una `tabla` de Teléfonos, con 30 teléfonos, y el último teléfono tiene `id=30`. Si decido crear un nuevo teléfono, mediante `spring-data JPA`, lo crea con `id=32`. Y así sucesivamente, crearía los siguientes con `id=34`, `id=36`...

¿Alguien sabe como crear los ids que corresponden? En el caso del ejemplo, sería `id=31`.
En mi `entity`, tengo anotado `id` con `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`.

Entity Phone:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Audited
public class Phone{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int number;
}
```

Controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/savePhone")
    public Book savePhone(@RequestBody Phone phone) {
        return phoneRepository.save(phone);
    }
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface PhoneRepository extends RevisionRepository<Phone, Integer, Integer> , JpaRepository<Phone, Integer>{

}
```

***`NOTA:`*** He probado a cambiar el `GenerationType`, con los valores de `TABLE`, `IDENTITY` Y `SEQUENCE`, pero no me han valido. De hecho, siempre he trabajado con `GenerationType.AUTO`, y me ha funcionado bien, no entiendo que tengo mal configurado.

Actualizo: La generación de mis tablas en la base de datos se hace automáticamente mediante el fichero .yaml con JPA, de la siguiente manera:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes definida la tabla en la base de datos?

Comment: Hola @PabloLozano , la tabla se autogeneró sola mediante JPA, no tuve que definirla yo a mano o mediante script. Quedó con un id no nulo y de tipo int4, junto con name y number que son varchar e int4

Comment: Es raro que con `GenerationType.IDENTITY` no te haya funcionado. Eso debería haber resuelto el problema. Alternativamente prueba setear en tu application.properties la propiedad `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false` y comenta si te funcionó.